# Installing Qt 5.x on Ubuntu globally

Tags: 16.04, application-development, qt, qml, qt5

**Hello everyone! :)**

I need to install Qt 5 globally on Ubuntu to be able to use QML libraries like Kirigami. However, the wast majority of Google search results tell how to install it locally (as a folder) from Qt's official website. How can I install Qt 5.x as a set of packages to get something functionally equivalent to Qt installation from *qt.io*?
I use Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my x64 PC.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will probably cover it:

```
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls
```

Comment: I have previously installed some other Qt packages, so both ones you've mentions are already installed. However, when I try to launch a sample app ("Stickman"), it says "/home/ilya/stickman/graphicsview.h:44: error: QtWidgets/QGraphicsView: No such file or directory". Also, Qt from qt.io comes with lots of QML samples.

Comment: QGraphicsView is in QtWidgets, so it's not useful when working with QtQuick.

Comment: Oh, thanks :) I'll try working with QML and write back.

Comment: Compiling a sample QML-Material application produces the following error message: /home/ilya/demo/main.cpp:1: error: QGuiApplication: No such file or directory

Comment: It should be in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/QGuiApplication`. It's in `qtbase5-dev` package which is installed by `qtdeclarative5-dev`.

Comment: The problem is that on compilation Qt uses headers for Qt 4, although Qt 5 is selected as default both in Qt Creator and systemwide. Now trying to solve.

Comment: The problem was in "Desktop" configuration. Now solved and things seem to work poperly. Thanks so much for help :)